# Is It Possible To A Link To The Homepage From The Admin Sidebar?

Tags: menus, admin, urls, homepage, admin-menu

The closest I've managed to get is:

```
function redirect_to_local_110(){
  wp_redirect("/", 302);
  exit;
}

function add_home_link() {
    add_menu_page( 'Course', 'Course', 'read', 'home', 'redirect_to_local_110', 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_home_link', 1001 );
```

However, even though the function `redirect_to_local_110` is called, the rendered link is `admin.php?page=home`.

How can I have a top-level menu item that links to the homepage?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the rendered link is `admin.php?page=home`? Does the menu item redirect to the home page?

Comment: @engelen I mean the link rendered to the `href` attribute of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

The $location parameter was incorrect. Try this:

```
function redirect_to_local_110(){
 wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit;
}

function add_home_link() {
    add_menu_page( 'Course', 'Course', 'read', 'home', 'redirect_to_local_110', 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_home_link', 1001 );
```

Or you could use this:

```
function redirect_to_local_110(){
 wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 );
  exit;
}

function add_home_link() {
    add_menu_page( 'Course', 'Course', 'read', 'home', 'redirect_to_local_110', 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_home_link', 1001 );
```

Comment: It makes no difference if I hard-code a url or grab it using `home_url()` in `redirect_to_local_110`. The url in the menu item anchor tag will be `admin.php?page=home` either way.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP headers are already sent when you are inside your `redirect_to_local_110()` function, so you risk the :

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

message.

You can try and verify it within your function:

```
function redirect_to_local_110()
{
    if( headers_sent() )
    {
        echo 'oh, headers are already sent, so we better not use wp_redirect() here!';
    }
}
```

Another (hacky) option would be to modify the link with Javascript, something like:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', function(){
    $link = home_url( '/' ); // Modify to your needs.
    echo '<script>
        jQuery( function($){
            $("#adminmenu a.toplevel_page_home").attr( "href", "' . esc_url( $link ) . '" );
        });
    </script>';
});
```

*ps:* it would be probably be more clean to use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), but it feels a bit too much to load an external javascript file with only one short line! ;-)